# Sorting by week in Google Analaytics Sheets add on

Tags: google-sheets, google-analytics

I just want to run a simple weekly traffic report with the Google Analytics Sheets add on. It does work fine, but I can't seem to figure out how to sort the weeks in chronological order with the jump from 2019 to 2020.

This is how it looks like

[Order of the weeks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvIUK.png)

Does anybody know what Order I need to enter to have the order from week 38 - 53 and then continue with 1,2...?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: alrighty. I'll ask there then. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Include the year as dimension and order by year and by week, like this:

```
year week
2019 38
2019 39
2019 40
...
2020 1
2020 2
2020 3
```

Answer (score 0):

For multi year weekly analysis, it's better to just use the corresponding Mondays for any date for your grouping/summing/analysis than it is to use "Week Numbers"

Those mondays can be obtained by using this arrayformula, assuming your dates were in column A (A2:A)

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,FLOOR(A2:A+5,7)-5))